# Dynamic Top N Filtering

Tags: charts, filtering, powerbi

I have recently moved from Tibco Spotfire to Microsoft PowerBI.
In Spotfire if I used dynamic filtering e.g. filtered the data from a leading bar chart and had another chart from the same data set but with a granular level, I could select an item from the leading bar chart and if I have the secondary chart set to the Top 10 items, it would dynamically filter that chart for the top 10 sub items from the group I selected in the first chart.

As a new user to PowerBI this does not seem to the case with chart filtering.
If I set a top 10 chart then filter from the leading chart, the top 10 chart always displays the top 10 from the data source but will highlight an item if it happens to be in the selected item group.

Is there a way for the top 10 chart to dynamically filter to the item group from the leading chart filter?

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change interaction mode between the charts from "highlight" to "filter":

[image]

Once "Edit interactions" is selected, select the first chart, then select interaction type on the chart it should affect.

Comment: Wow it was that simple. Thank you very much.